# Absolute vs. Relative paths in HTML <head>

Tags: html, apache

I serve content from a subdirectory on my web server, for example:

```
http://www.myserver.com/subtree
```

I notice that the CSS is not rendering correctly, so I look at the source of the HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/stylesheets/style.css"/>
```

One would expect that browsers such as Chrome or Firefox attempt to find this css at

```
http://www.myserver.com/subtree/static/stylesheets/style.css
```

When hovering over the link, I can see that it links me to

```
http://www.myserver.com/static/stylesheets/style.css
```

It may be useful to note that I'm using apache's mod_proxy to serve the content from /subtree from another server running on the local machine. However, my reasoning is that the browser doesn't know about this and it looks like the content is coming from myserver.com/subtree so therefore it should look for the resources using the relative path.

What am I missing?

Comment: The browser seems not treating "subtree" as a folder, it is just treated like a file. may be you should use "subtree/" if possible ?

Comment: I've noticed that with friendly URLs, browsers will often look in a different relative path depending on whether or not you include a trailing slash.  I.E, `http://www.myserver.com/subtree` would have a relative root of `http://www.myserver.com/`, and `http://www.myserver.com/subtree/` would have a relative root of `http://www.myserver.com/subtree/`

Comment: You may have a look at the `<base>`-html element

Comment: You should mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's to be expected. The browser cannot know that /subtree is a folder (instead, it could also be just a file served as text/html). If you want the browser to include this path fragment in relative path lookups, make sure that it ends with as slash, as in:

```
http://www.myserver.com/subtree/
```

If you are using Apache, you can use mod_dir's DirectorySlash directive to automatically fix this for you: [mod_dir documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help:

Browsers when see URLs which start with `/`, they remove the `path` part of the `document.location.href`, or get the value of `document.location.origin` and append the current URL to the end of it.

When they see URLs which don't start with '/', they append the current URL to the end of `document.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by Sam Dufel on the question:

> I've noticed that with friendly URLs,
>   browsers will often look in a
>   different relative path depending on
>   whether or not you include a trailing
>   slash. I.E,
>   http://www.myserver.com/subtree would
>   have a relative root of
>   http://www.myserver.com/, and
>   http://www.myserver.com/subtree/ would
>   have a relative root of
>   http://www.myserver.com/subtree/

(here so you can mark this question as answered)